# How to delete a dictionary from a dictionary if it doesn't contains a specific key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How do I delete dictionary which doesn't contain a specific key.
For example as bellow:

```
myList = [
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
        "status" : "value"
    },
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
        "status" : "value"
    },
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
    }
]
```

In the given example, the 3rd dictionary doesn't contain the "status" key, how do I delete that whole dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` to traverse each dict and then verify if there is the specific `key` as below:

```
myList = [
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
        "status" : "value"
    },
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
        "status" : "value"
    },
    {
        "name" : "value",
        "price" : "value",
        "details" : "value",
    }
]

print([ dic for dic in myList if dic.get('status', False)])
```

The `get` method returns the value of the `key` if it exits, otherwise returns `False`

The result would be:

```
[{'name': 'value', 'price': 'value', 'details': 'value', 'status': 'value'}, {'name': 'value', 'price': 'value', 'details': 'value', 'status': 'value'}]
```

Hope this can help you :)

Comment: ``dic.get('status', False)`` can be replace with ``dic.get('status')``

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way you can do is to check if key exists in the dictionary in a list comprehension:

```
[x for x in myList if 'status' in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to filter out based on a condition.

```
newList = [ item for item in myList if item.get("status") is not None]
```